# Unable to consume messages Kafka Spring Boot Docker Compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose, microservices

My code is working fine while running separately using IDE. But when using docker-compose, the producer produce the messages correctly and I can consume the messages using docker CLI composer also but my Spring Boot microservice responsible for consuming the messages is not consuming.

There are no Error shows in the consumer container (name: process), it logs only the following...

```
request.timeout.ms = 30000

retry.backoff.ms = 100

sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null

sasl.jaas.config = null

sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit

sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000

sasl.kerberos.service.name = null

sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05

sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8

sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null

sasl.login.class = null

sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300

sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60

sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8

sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05

sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI

security.protocol = PLAINTEXT

security.providers = null

send.buffer.bytes = 131072

session.timeout.ms = 10000

ssl.cipher.suites = null

ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]

ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https

ssl.engine.factory.class = null

ssl.key.password = null

ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509

ssl.keystore.location = null

ssl.keystore.password = null

ssl.keystore.type = JKS

ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2

ssl.provider = null

ssl.secure.random.implementation = null

ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX

ssl.truststore.location = null

ssl.truststore.password = null

ssl.truststore.type = JKS

value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer


2021-04-07 14:58:07.123 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser : Kafka version: 2.6.0

2021-04-07 14:58:07.126 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser : Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651

2021-04-07 14:58:07.127 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser : Kafka startTimeMs: 1617807487120

2021-04-07 14:58:07.138 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testgroup-1, groupId=testgroup] Subscribed to topic(s): test

2021-04-07 14:58:07.146 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler : Initializing ExecutorService

2021-04-07 14:58:07.241 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''

2021-04-07 14:58:07.354 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.h.p.p.ProcessFcmDataServiceApplication : Started ProcessFcmDataServiceApplication in 9.916 seconds (JVM running for 11.719)

2021-04-07 14:58:08.036 WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testgroup-1, groupId=testgroup] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

2021-04-07 14:58:08.037 WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testgroup-1, groupId=testgroup] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

2021-04-07 14:58:08.165 WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testgroup-1, groupId=testgroup] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

2021-04-07 14:58:08.165 WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testgroup-1, groupId=testgroup] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

2021-04-07 14:58:08.316 WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testgroup-1, groupId=testgroup] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

2021-04-07 14:58:08.317 WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testgroup-1, groupId=testgroup] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  register:
    container_name: register
    build: register-FCM-token-service/
    networks:
      - push-notification
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"

  send:
    container_name: send
    build: send-FCM-notification-service/
    networks:
      - push-notification
    depends_on:
      - process
    links:
      - kafka:kafka
    environment:
      kafka.boot.server: kafka:9092
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"

  process:
    container_name: process
    build: process-FCM-data-service/
    networks:
      - push-notification
    depends_on:
      - recieve
    links:
      - kafka:kafka
    environment:
      kafka.boot.server: kafka:9092
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
 
  recieve:
    container_name: recieve
    build: recieve-push-request-service/
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    links:
      - kafka:kafka
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      kafka.boot.server: kafka:9092
    networks:
      - push-notification 

  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    restart: always
    networks:
      - push-notification 

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - push-notification
    restart: always
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET: 'latest'

networks:
  push-notification:
```

The "process" container (the consumer) is not working.

When trying using the container CLI, the kafka consumer works fine inside the kafka container, here is the output...

```
/ # kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
{"source":"salesforce","userid":"1235aa","messageTitle":"test 1 title","messageBody":"test 1 body"}
```

Here is my Kafka Config Java file for the process microservice (the consumer)...

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.boot.server}")
    private String kafkaServer;
    
    @Value("${kafka.consumer.group.id}")
    private String kafkaGroupId;
    
    public ProducerFactory<String, PushMessageModel> getProducerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);    //use StringSerializer.class instead for simple string value 
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, PushMessageModel> getKafkaTemplate(){
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(getProducerFactory());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, FCMMessageContainer> getConsumerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(FCMMessageContainer.class));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, FCMMessageContainer>> getKafkaListener(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, FCMMessageContainer> listener = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        listener.setConsumerFactory(getConsumerFactory());
        listener.setErrorHandler(new KafkaErrHandler());
        return listener;
    }
}
```

How can I debug this issue? How to resolve this? There is no issue with my code clearly as it works on the IDE, then what is the problem?

Comment: Where did you get the environment variable names `kafka.boot.server` from? By default Spring Boot will want `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`.

Comment: I have overridden the Kafka config files, hence I have used my custom environment variables.

Comment: You overrode the Kafka config files? But what about the Spring Boot config files?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say, I have used custom Kafka config class inside my application, I have updated my question with that.

Comment: How are you putting your environment variables into the application.properties? And again, Spring has a default `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` property, so why try using anything else?

Comment: Kindly go through this link if you have any doubts on how to use environment variables to override application.properties' values, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

And as I have already mentioned that all the microservice with Kafka is working fine while running on IDE, and the producer is working fine inside docker container using the same environment variable, I have no idea how this questions are relevant regarding this thread!